# Cannot detect the Connected Smartcard

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader

I want to be able to detect the smartcard reader and then detect if the smartcard has been inserted to the smartcard reader or not. When running the code below I get the error Debug Assertion failed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winscard.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winscard.lib")

HRESULT __cdecl main()
{
HRESULT           hr = S_OK;
LPTSTR            szReaders, szRdr;
DWORD             cchReaders = SCARD_AUTOALLOCATE;
DWORD             dwI, dwRdrCount;
SCARD_READERSTATE rgscState[MAXIMUM_SMARTCARD_READERS];
TCHAR             szCard[MAX_PATH];
SCARDCONTEXT      hSC;
LONG              lReturn;

// Establish the card to watch for.
// Multiple cards can be looked for, but
// this sample looks for only one card.
_tcscat_s ( szCard, MAX_PATH * sizeof(TCHAR), TEXT("GemSAFE"));
szCard[lstrlen(szCard) + 1] = 0;  // Double trailing zero.

// Establish a context.
lReturn = SCardEstablishContext(SCARD_SCOPE_USER,
                                NULL,
                                NULL,
                                &hSC );
if ( SCARD_S_SUCCESS != lReturn )
{
    printf("Failed SCardEstablishContext\n");
    exit(1);
}

// Determine which readers are available.
lReturn = SCardListReaders(hSC,
                           NULL,
                           (LPTSTR)&szReaders,
                           &cchReaders );
if ( SCARD_S_SUCCESS != lReturn )
{
    printf("Failed SCardListReaders\n");
    exit(1);
}
// Place the readers into the state array.
szRdr = szReaders;
for ( dwI = 0; dwI < MAXIMUM_SMARTCARD_READERS; dwI++ )
{
    if ( 0 == *szRdr )
        break;
    rgscState[dwI].szReader = szRdr;
    rgscState[dwI].dwCurrentState = SCARD_STATE_UNAWARE;
    szRdr += lstrlen(szRdr) + 1;
}
dwRdrCount = dwI;

// If any readers are available, proceed.
if ( 0 != dwRdrCount )
{
  for (;;)
  { 
    // Look for the card.
    lReturn = SCardLocateCards(hSC,
                               szCard,
                               rgscState,
                               dwRdrCount );
    if ( SCARD_S_SUCCESS != lReturn )
    {
        printf("Failed SCardLocateCards\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Look through the array of readers.
    for ( dwI=0; dwI < dwRdrCount; dwI++)
    {
        if ( 0 != ( SCARD_STATE_ATRMATCH & 
                    rgscState[dwI].dwEventState))
        {
           _tprintf( TEXT("Card '%s' found in reader '%s'.\n"),
                     szCard,
                     rgscState[dwI].szReader );
            SCardFreeMemory( hSC,
                             szReaders );
            return 0;  // Context will be release automatically.
        }
        // Update the state.
        rgscState[dwI].dwCurrentState = rgscState[dwI].dwEventState;
    }

  // Card not found yet; wait until there is a change.
  lReturn = SCardGetStatusChange(hSC,
                                 INFINITE, // infinite wait
                                 rgscState,
                                 dwRdrCount );
  if ( SCARD_S_SUCCESS != lReturn )
  {
    printf("Failed SCardGetStatusChange\n");
    exit(1);
  }
 }  // for (;;)
}
else
    printf("No readers available\n");

// Release the context.
lReturn = SCardReleaseContext(hSC);
if ( SCARD_S_SUCCESS != lReturn )
{
    printf("Failed SCardReleaseContext\n");
    exit(1);
}

SCardFreeMemory( hSC,
                 szReaders );

return hr;
}
```

Error:
[image]

UPDATE:
I added

```
memset(rgscState, 0, sizeof(SCARD_READERSTATE);
```

to the code and it worked. But it doesnot still locate the smartcard inserted to the smartcard reader. When the card is detected the following code should be neglected but as it didnot find the inserted smartcard it runs the following code.

```
 if ( SCARD_S_SUCCESS != lReturn )
    {
        printf("Failed SCardLocateCards\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested , I added

```
memset(rgscState, 0, sizeof(SCARD_READERSTATE);
```

and I don't get the error anymore.